# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.base' while running util.py file

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, pickle, modulenotfounderror

I encountered a ModuleNotFoundError while running the server. The error occurs when the script attempts to load the model using pickle. It specifically states that no module is named 'sklearn.linear_model.base'.

[util.py](https://github.com/codebasics/py/blob/801ee0ee4d342fd22b89915dc0c4864250a0ec10/DataScience/BangloreHomePrices/server/util.py)

**Error Details :**

```
loading saved artifacts...start
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Code\BHP\server\util.py", line 47, in
load_saved_artifacts()
File "C:\Code\BHP\server\util.py", line 37, in load_saved_artifacts
__model = pickle.load(f)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.linear_model.base'
```

**Context:**

This error is occurring in the load_saved_artifacts() function within util.py. The issue seems to be related to the loading of the machine learning model using pickle. It suggests that the necessary module or package (sklearn.linear_model.base) is not found during the loading process.

**Potential Solutions Attempted:**

Module Installation: I have attempted to install the required module using pip, but the issue persists.

Alternative Approach: I have also tried using joblib as an alternative to pickle for model persistence, but the error still occurs.

**Additional Notes:**

The server and utility files seem correct, but there might be an underlying issue with the environment or dependencies.

It's possible there could be a conflict between different versions of libraries or an issue with the Python environment configuration.

Any assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you refer to the `util.py` code in a Github repository.
The problem is:
That code can change, perhaps even because of the answer.
Stackoverflow is meant to be a repository for quality questions with quality answers, where people can find an answer to a problem they have.
It is okay to reference the code in the github, but you should also post the relevant code at least as snippet here on StackOverflow, so that the relevant code stays connected to the question.